# How to wrap control to custom ControlValueAccessor respecting the validation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have a matDatePicker that I use all over the application with reactive forms, like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input formControlName="ratingDate" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" 
         placeholder="Rating Date" (dateInput)="performnCustomValidation)">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

However, there is a validation bug, that I need to solve by some additional event handling:

```
performnCustomValidation(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
  var strValue = (event.targetElement as HTMLInputElement).value
  if (event.value === null && strValue) {
    this.dateFormControl.setErrors({ isDate: true }, { emitEvent: true});
  }
}
```

So I've decided to wrap this into custom control.

**How do I get the validation working in my custom wrapper component, just like it was before?**

That means it has to respect

1. the built in matDatePicker validation
2. the FormControl validators
3. my custom validation error
4. Validation state must be reflected by the same visual as it was before

So far I have this, but no validation

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-date-picker',
  template: `
<mat-form-field class="large-input" floatLabel="always">
    <input #input1 matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" (dateChange)="performCustomValidation($event)">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>`,
  styleUrls: ['./date-picker.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => DatePickerComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class DatePickerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(MatInput) matInput;
  @ViewChild('input1') input;


  private control: FormControl;

  onChange: any = (date: Date) => { };
  onTouched: any = () => { };

  constructor(private injector: Injector,
  ) {

   }

  // The form control is only set after initialization
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const ngControl: NgControl = this.injector.get(NgControl, null);
    if (ngControl) {
      this.control = ngControl.control as FormControl;
    } else {
    }
  }


  performnCustomValidation(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
    var strValue = (event.targetElement as HTMLInputElement).value
    if (event.value === null && strValue) {
      this.dateFormControl.setErrors({ isDate: true }, { emitEvent: true});
    }
  }

  writeValue(value) {
    this.matInput.value = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  // We implement this method to keep a reference to the onTouched
  //callback function passed by the forms API
  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
}
```